# yii2 codeception doesn't generate unit suit

Tags: yii2, codeception

I red a ton of documentation and posts and it seems that almost everyone has problems with those yii2 codeception tests. My problem is that when I try to generate unit suit `./vendor/bin/codecept generate:test unit Login` I get an error

```
In Configuration.php line 306:  Suite unit was not loaded
```

What can cause this ? Have not found answer anywhere. Thank you!

EDIT - unit.suite.yml

```
suite_namespace: backend\tests\unit
suite_class: UnitTester
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Yii2:
            part: [orm, email, fixtures]
        - Asserts
```

Comment: Does tests/unit directory exist? You have to execute `codecept bootstrap` command first.

Comment: Yes, I executed it and the directory exits. Still can't get it. I  made the file manually for now .. still searching for decision.

Comment: You have no tests/unit.suite.yml file, have you?

Comment: No, I have it. `./vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` adds the files. Maybe it's something in my unit.suite.yml. Will edit it in the question above.

Answer (score 6):

The suite has to be specified. To specify it use `-c backend`

And the whole command should be:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept generate:test unit Login -c backend
```